# Symbol.hasInstance Property working in JS

Tags: javascript

I understand that `Symbol.hasInstance` property can be cutomised to check if an object is an instance of a particular class. But what i don't understand is how this is working ?
Example:

```js
class Animal {
 static [Symbol.hasInstance](obj){ // how is this obj being passes here on calling the function below
    if(obj.isAnimal) return true
 }
}

const a1 = new Animal();
console.log(a1 instanceOf Animal) // false 
a1.isAnimal = true
console.log(a1 instanceOf Animal) // true
```

**Question**: How is obj being passed to the static function on calling `a1 instanceOf Animal`

Comment: read it in reverse, means `a1` is  passed as argument to Animal.<instanceof> function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many times when a function can be called even if you don't have anything in the code that does so explicitly with `()`s after the property name. For example, with iterators:

```js
class C {
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) yield i;
  }
}
const c = new C();
for (const item of c) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

And type coercion:

```js
const obj = {
  toString: () => 'some obj'
};
console.log(String(obj));
```

And proxies.

```js
const prox = new Proxy({}, {
  has() {
    console.log('has invoked');
    return true;
  }
});
console.log('foo' in prox);
```

`instanceof` is just another one of these circumstances.

`x instanceof y` [is specified to](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-instanceofoperator) first extract the value at the `hasInstance` symbol from `y`, if such a value exists:

> 2. Let instOfHandler be ? GetMethod(target, @@hasInstance).

and then it'll be invoked with `x`. If the value doesn't exist,[`OrdinaryHasInstance`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryhasinstance) will be called with `x` and `y` instead. That's all there really is to it - `instanceof`, by definition, will look up and try to call a `Symbol.hasInstance` property if there is one.

For almost all operators, you can think of `x someOperator y` as invoking `someOperator` with `x` and `y` - and the operator often does a number of things with the operands behind the scenes.

Comment: Okay this really cleared things out ! Thanks a lot ! where can i know this stuff ? Specification ?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much - it's pretty dense, but it's often a good source of the basics of why something in the language operates the way it does, if you can't find the topic in a more easily accessible tutorial. Even if you don't understand all the words and symbols, it'll let you connect the dots.